# Static method returning an instance of its class

Tags: python, static-methods

Is it possible for static method of a class to return a new instance of its class.

```
class Foo(object):
    @staticmethod
    def return_new():
        "returns a new instance of the class"
        new_instance = ???
        return new_instance
```

I want it so any subclass of Foo will return the subclass rather than a Foo instance. So replacing ??? with Foo() will not do.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Why don't you use [`classmethod`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod)? Using `classmethod`, the method receives the class as the first parameter (`cls` in the following example).

```
class Foo(object):
    @classmethod
    def return_new(cls):
        "returns a new instance of the class"
        new_instance = cls()
        return new_instance

class Bar(Foo):
    pass

assert isinstance(Foo.return_new(), Foo)
assert isinstance(Bar.return_new(), Bar)
```

Comment: Because I didn't know they existed.
I'm assuming that cls is the class object of the instance. No?

Comment: @TonisF.Piip : `cls` is the class on which the method is called.

Comment: And yet, type annotation `-> Foo` is not allowed? Hum.

Comment: @Raphael, It is support in 3.7+. you should use `from __future__ import annotations` to use forward reference.

Comment: @falsetru Very cool, thanks! (Turns out I may be stuck on 3.6 until the next Ubuntu LTS, but then... ;D)

Comment: @Raphael, In Python 3.6, you can use `-> 'Foo'` as workaround. (NOTE: `Foo` quoted)

Comment: @falsetru But that's not accurate typing... as that's saying it will always return a instance of Foo. But if you were to subclass Foo with class Baz,  `return_new` will return Baz, not Foo. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46007544/python-3-type-hint-for-a-factory-method-on-a-base-class-returning-a-child-class has the correct answer, but even then it doesn't explicitly say it covers that case. :thinky:

Comment: @TonisF.Piip, UPDATE: In Python 3.11+, you can use [`typing.Self`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Self).

Comment: But what about python 3.10?

Comment: @TonisF.Piip, Try [`typing_extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/).