# Python 3 type hint for a factory method on a base class returning a child class instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

Let's say I have two classes `Base` and `Child` with a factory method in `Base`. The factory method calls another classmethod which may be overriden by `Base`'s child classes.

```
class Base(object):
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, *args: Tuple) -> 'Base':
        value = cls._prepare(*args)
        return cls(value)

    @classmethod
    def _prepare(cls, *args: Tuple) -> Any:
        return args[0] if args else None

    def __init__(self, value: Any) -> None:
        self.value = value


class Child(Base):
    @classmethod
    def _prepare(cls, *args: Tuple) -> Any:
        return args[1] if len(args) > 1 else None

    def method_not_present_on_base(self) -> None:
        pass
```

Is there a way to annotate `Base.create` so that a static type checker could infer that `Base.create()` returned an instance of `Base` and `Child.create()` returned an instance of `Child`, so that the following example would pass static analysis?

```
base = Base.create(1)
child = Child.create(2, 3)
child.method_not_present_on_base()
```

In the above example a static type checker would rightfully complain that the `method_not_present_on_base` is, well, not present on the `Base` class.

---

I thought about turning `Base` into a generic class and having the child classes specify themselves as type arguments, i.e. bringing the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to Python.

```
T = TypeVar('T')

class Base(Generic[T]):
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, *args: Tuple) -> T: ...

class Child(Base['Child']): ...
```

But this feels rather unpythonic with CRTP coming from C++ and all...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type annotation for classmethod returning instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44640479/type-annotation-for-classmethod-returning-instance)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It is indeed possible: the feature is called [TypeVar with Generic Self](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#generic-methods-and-generic-self) (though this is slightly misleading because we're using this for a class method in this case). I believe it behaves roughly equivalently to the "CRTP" technique you linked to (though I'm not a C++ expert so can't say for certain).

In any case, you would declare your base and child classes like so:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type, Tuple

T = TypeVar('T', bound='Base')

class Base:
    @classmethod
    def create(cls: Type[T], *args: Tuple[Any]) -> T: ...

class Child(Base):
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, *args: Tuple[Any]) -> 'Child': ...
```

Note that:

1. We don't need to make the class itself generic since we only need a generic function
2. Setting the TypeVar's bound to 'Base' is strictly speaking optional, but is probably a good idea: this way, the callers of your base class/subclasses will at least be able to call methods defined in the base class even if you don't know exactly which subclass you're dealing with.
3. We can omit the annotation on `cls` for the child definition.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Unfortunately, PyCharm now treats private methods on `cls` as accessing a private member on another object but mypy treats this as expected.

Comment: Can you change the type hint of an inherited method without actually overriding it? .... https://stackoverflow.com/q/49583643/2823755

Comment: @wwii -- in response to your question above, no, not really. In response to the question you linked to, you can solve your issue by making BaseRepository a generic class. Basically, you're defining a custom collection, so approach your problem the same way you'd define a custom collection in Java or C# or whatever.

Comment: `cls: Type[T]` , then how do i use cls to access to other method? `cls.other_method()`  (`other_method` is the method of `Base` class) doesn't work anymore

Comment: This doesn't work for me. If I replace your `...` in `Base.create` with `Child.create(*args)`, it says `Incompatible return value type (got "Child", expected "T")`.

Comment: It seems even an incorrect return type in the overriding method passes typecheck, is there any solution? [Example](https://gist.github.com/jacksonthall22/93f121be22fef3844b634d21068026e1)

Answer (score 12):

Python 3.11 now has a Self type, in case anyone else also stumbled on this old question. `mypy` support [was added](https://mypy-lang.blogspot.com/2023/02/mypy-10-released.html) in version `1.0`, available on PyPI since Feb. 2023.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Self

It's a DRY way of annotating the return value of class method factories:

```
from typing import Self
from collections import defaultdict

class NestedDefaultDict(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(NestedDefaultDict, *args, **kwargs)
      
    @classmethod  
    def from_nested_dict(cls, dict_) -> Self:
        inst = NestedDefaultDict()
        for key, val in dict_.items():
            inst[key] = cls.from_nested_dict(val) if isinstance(val, dict) else val
        return inst
```

Self's great for method chaining APIs too.  I've copied the Self-less example below from James Murphy's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BY34Fe-2xgk&t=1s), and just added the 3 annotations.

```
# https://github.com/mCodingLLC/VideosSampleCode/blob/master/videos/095_method_chaining_and_self/method_chaining_and_self.py

class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, position, fatigue=0):
        self.name = name
        self.position = position
        self.fatigue = fatigue

    def draw(self) -> Self:
        print(f"drawing {self.name} to screen at {self.position}")
        return self

    def move(self, delta) -> Self:
        self.position += delta
        self.fatigue += 1
        return self

    def rest(self) -> Self:
        self.fatigue = 0
        return self
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! Could you extend your answer with a code snippet that maybe shows the usage with `@classmethod`s?

Comment: It's only a type annotation, but I'd be happy to.

Comment: Oh, you're OP.  I did try mypy with your original example annotated with Self: 
`def create(cls, *args: Tuple) -> Self`  But unfortunately it's not supported by mypy, at least not just yet.  Watch this space though - they've been working on it for a number of months.  There's good support for Self from lots of other tools already.