# How to implement CRTP functionality in python?

Tags: python, c++, crtp

I want to access a member (variable) of a derived class from a base class in python. In `c++` I can use the CRTP design pattern for this. In c++, for example, I would do something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>


template <class derived>
class Base {

    public:
        void get_value()
            {
            double value = static_cast<derived *> (this) -> myvalue_;
            std::cout<< "This is the derived value: " << value << std::endl;
        }

};
```

```cpp
class derived:public Base<derived>{

    public:

        double myvalue_;

        derived(double &_myvalue)
            {
                myvalue_ = _myvalue;
            }
};
```

Usage:

```cpp
int main(){

    double some_value=5.0;
    derived myclass(some_value);
    myclass.get_value();
    // This prints on screen "This is the derived value: 5"
};
```

Any way I can implement this functionality in python?

What I want to do is to have a **single** base class that has a common set of functions that are based on derived class member *variables*.  I want to avoid rewriting/repeating this common set of functions in all derived classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is what you are looking for, but as long as the `subclass` has an attribute, even though it's not defined in the `baseclass` it will be able to access it through the instance.

```
class Base(object):
    def getValue(self):
        print(self.myvalue)



class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self, myvalue):
        self.myvalue = myvalue



val = 3
derived = Derived(3)
derived.getValue()
#>3
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you should take a step back and ask, why do we even use CRTP in C++.  The reason for CRTP is that we might want to use a class polymorphically at compile-time or elide the virtual function call overhead.

Now Python does not have a “compile time” and because it is not statically typed all function calls are essentially virtual.  Thus, you will obtain the same behaviour as with CRTP just with regular inheritance.

```
class Base(object):
    def get_value(self):
        print("This is the derived value:", self.value)

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

d = Derived(5)
d.get_value() # prints "This is the derived value: 5"
```

<kbd>[Live example](https://ideone.com/ofqPLr)</kbd>

If, on the other hand you want CRTP to interact with the Python3 `typing` system, then you might want to checkout this question: [Python 3 type hint for a factory method on a base class returning a child class instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46007544)

Comment: In the OP's case 'self.value' was defined in the 'Derived', so the Base class doesn't know about it.

Comment: Thank you for your time for the additional explanation. I need the self.value to be on the Derived class and not exist on the Base class.

Comment: Would a CRTP-style approach be of value in the case of a decorated base-class method? Not rhetorical, honestly asking about this.