# how make super class refer to itself

Tags: python-3.x, class, multiple-inheritance, mixins, super

I want to make a mixin class refer to its own class during its init.

If I make it refer to `self.__class__` then it refers to the class of the instance it is mixed into, not its own class. If it refers to `mx.__class__` if refers to class 'type'.

```
class mx:
    def __init__(self):
        print( self.__class__ )
        print( mx.__class__ )

class C( mx ):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

>>> o = C()
<class '__main__.C'>
<class 'type'>
```

If, on the other hand, I create it as an instance of its own, it gets the class reference I seek when it refers to self.

```
>>> m = mx()
<class '__main__.mx'>
<class 'type'>
```

How can I get mx to refer to `<class '... .mx'>` from itself?

Comment: ... `print(mx)`?

Comment: Sort of the opposite of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48055678/how-to-implement-crtp-functionality-in-python

Comment: ah thku so much, jonr - tis good to be able to get such quick relief for such a stoopid question. I had got it into my head (though my example above suggests otherwise) that the class could not refer to itself during init cos it was not yet created. Whereas I had merely used the wrong class name (complex class name, recently given another letter on the end), which is why the class was not recognised. Anyway, yours is an answer, and shd get a point for it. Thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to make a mixin class refer to its own class during its init.

The question is confusing because you are asking how to access the current class dynamically, but are actually expecting a static result. I would instead recommend using `mx` instead.

Comment: thnku Mr.Soul. That is the answer. But jonrsharpe got in there first. If only he would make his answer as an answer, I would give him the tick.