# How to hint the return type of an alternative constructor from a base class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I'm wondering how to use type hinting to define the return type of the "load" function in the following situation:

```
class BaseClass:

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, path) -> '??????':  # Should return a cls object
        constructor_args = load_from_file(path)
        return cls(**constructor_args)

class ImplementationClass(BaseClass):
    ...
```

I would like to have automatic type inference (in the IDE) to indicate that `my_implementation` is going to be an `ImplementationClass` instance:

```
my_implementation = ImplementationClass.load('/path/to/file.pkl')
```

Is there a way to do this in Python?

## Answer:

This question was correctly marked as a duplicate.  In this case, the correct answer (based on the [answer to the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46064289/851699)) is

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type

T = TypeVar('T', bound = 'BaseClass')

class BaseClass:

    @classmethod
    def load(cls: Type[T], path) -> T:  # Should return a cls object
        constructor_args = load_from_file`(path)
        return cls(**constructor_args)

class ImplementationClass(BaseClass):

    def my_method(self):
        pass


my_instance = ImplementationClass.load('/path/to/file')
my_instance.my_method()  # Type checker is happy with this line now
```

Comment: Do you _need_ it to be `ImplementationClass` or is it fine to have it be `BaseClass`?

Comment: `ImplementationClass`, otherwise I would of course just do `-> 'BaseClass'`

Comment: Well in that case, your implementation would not match the type you wish to specify

Comment: To be clear, `ImplementationClass.load(path)` returns an `ImplementationClass` - and I would like to specify it as such without duplicating the `load` method.  It looks from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46064289/851699) like it is possible.

Comment: As long as the only thing returned from `BaseClass` is `ImplementationClass`, then you can just say `def load(_cls, path: Path) -> 'ImplementationClass': ...`. But the sample implementation you provided means that it is any subclass of `BaseClass`

Comment: `BaseClass.load` should return an object of whatever class (BaseClass or a sublass of it) it is called on.  See answer above.